# Solving a system of non linear equations with 3 variables - Error in fsolve (line 230)

Tags: matlab

Hello im a total matlab beginner and barely know any programming but i gotta solve a certain system of equations and thus resorted to this. So far i've created this script:

```
function F=caudales(a)
    
    x = a(1);
    y = a(2);
    z = a(3);
    
    F(1)=6.078*10^-4*z^1.85+8.864*10^-9*x^1.85-0.01078
    F(2)=9.018*10^-8*y^1.85+8.864*10^-9*x^1.85-0.009078
    F(3)=y+z-x
end
```

and saved it with the recommended name "caudales"

now on the workspace i think is called i've wrote this:

```
ag

ag =

     1
     1
     1

>> a = fsolve(@caudales,ag)
```

yet i get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'caudales'.

Error in fsolve (line 230)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
```

Comment: Is the function in path? i.e. is it for example in the same folder where you are running `fsolve`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri oooooh i didnt know the command window kinda worked on a certain folder where the function script should be present, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thanks to a commenter i learnt that the issue was that fsolve was not running in the same window were i had saved the script for the functions, and thus it could not find it.

I had to modify the current folder of the command window and then the function
ran perfectly.